# How to use switch in a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an output from a function converted by switch statement:

```js
function switchItUp(number) {
  switch (number) {
    case 1:
      let output = 'one';
      break;
    default:
  }
  return output
}

console.log(switchItUp(1));
```

Comment: `let` is scoped to the switch statement. You'll need to declare `output` outside the switch, and then update it within the case statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `output` in the outer scope (function's)

```js
function switchItUp(number) {
  let output;
  switch (number) {
    case 1:
      output = 'one';
      break;
    default:
  }
  return output
}
console.log(switchItUp(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define output variable out of switch and in switch assign value to it

```
function switchItUp(number) {
  let output;
  switch (number) {
    case 1:
      output = 'one';
      break;
    default:
  }
  return output
}
console.log(switchItUp(1))
```

or more simple you can return where switch breaks :

```js
function switchItUp(number) {
  switch (number) {
    case 1:
      return  'one';
    default: 
  }
}
console.log(switchItUp(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function switchItUp(number) {
  switch (number) {
    case 1:
      let output = 'one';
      return output;
    default:
  }

}

console.log(switchItUp(1));
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to define the `output` to before the switch statement like below:

```
function switchItUp(number) {   
  let output;
  switch (number) {
     case 1:
       output = 'one';
       break;
     default:
  }
  return output
}
```

Hope this will works for you